Showing that the union of two families of disjoint sets is disjoint?
I misread a theorem in my textbook and ended up with the following statement:
Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be nonempty families of sets, where every element of $\mathcal{F}$ is disjoint from every element of $\mathcal{G}$. Prove that $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ and $\bigcup \mathcal{G}$ are disjoint.
Here is a draft of my attempted proof:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be nonempty families of sets, and suppose every element of $\mathcal{F}$ is disjoint from every element of $\mathcal{G}$.
Let $A$ be an arbitrary set in $\mathcal{F}$, and choose an arbitrary element $a \in A$. So, $a \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$.
Then for all $B \in \mathcal{G}$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$. In particular, $a \notin B$, and $a \notin \bigcup \mathcal{G}$.
Since $a$ was an arbitrary element in $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$, $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \cap \bigcup \mathcal{G} = \emptyset$.

I feel like something is wrong at the end of my proof, and I don't even know if the theorem I wrote here is correct. I've seen many counterexamples on MSE involving $\{\emptyset\}$ for similar questions, but I didn't grasp them enough to apply them here. Could someone provide clarification on whether the theorem is correct and, if not, explain why? Also, if my proof is flawed, could you point out where it goes wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance for your help!

First of all, do you mean $\bigcup\limits_{F\in\mathcal F} F$ ?

@Euclid Yes, $[x\in\bigcup A\Leftrightarrow \exists y,(y\in A\land x\in y)]$ is a standard notation. Likewise, $[x\in\bigcap A\Leftrightarrow \forall y,(y\in A\to x\in y)]$. See Jech, Hrbacek, Introduction to Set Theory.

@Euclid The textbook defined $\cup \mathcal{F}$ to be the union of the family $\mathcal{F}$!!

You have the right idea but you should start with "Let $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F}$" and show $x \notin \bigcup \mathcal{G}$. When you start with "Let $A$ be an arbitrary set in $\mathcal{F}$", it's not as obvious how that's related to your goal of showing $\bigcup \mathcal{F} \cap \bigcup \mathcal{G} = \emptyset$. Even more straightforward is to start with "Let $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F} \cap \bigcup \mathcal{G}$" and derive a contradiction.

@JairTaylor I didn't realize that--thank you so much!

It should be rather trivial: suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is
$$x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F} \cap \bigcup \mathcal{G}$$
Then there exists some $F_x \in \mathcal{F}$ and $G_x \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $x \in F_x \cap G_x$. This contradicts the hypothesis that "every element of $\mathcal{F}$ is disjoint from every element of $\mathcal{G}$".

Your proof is correct.
Alternatively, using properties of intersection and union of sets, we get $$\bigcup\mathcal{F}\cap \bigcup\mathcal{G}= \left(\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{F}}A\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{G}}B\right)=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{F},B\in\mathcal{G}} (A\cap B)=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{F},B\in\mathcal{G}} \emptyset=\emptyset$$
